# TypeError: Cannot read property '_events' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why am I getting this error?

```
events.js:133
  if (this._events === undefined ||
           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '_events' of undefined
    at EventEmitter.init (events.js:133:12)
    at EventEmitter (events.js:66:21)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Coding\Online\Node.js\FreeCodeCamp\les2_TheEventModuleAndEventEmitterClass\app.js:10:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)   
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:10
92:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)        
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)

    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/ru
n_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
PS D:\Coding\Online\Node.js\FreeCodeCamp\les2_TheEventModuleAndEventEmitterClass>
```

I only wrote this:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
const eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();


class Person extends EventEmitter(){
    constructor(name){
        super();
        this._name = name;
    }
    get name(){
        return this._name;
    }
}

let pedro = new Person('Pedro');
pedro.on('name',()=>{
    console.log('my name is ' + pedro.name);
});

pedro.emit('name')
```

Where am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi! Can you share the code from `EventEmitter`? This is getting pulled in with your `require` statement. This appears to be where the error is getting thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding parenthesis on class declaration. Your code should be:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
const eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();


class Person extends EventEmitter { // This is what was changed
    constructor(name){
        super();
        this._name = name;
    }
    get name(){
        return this._name;
    }
}

let pedro = new Person('Pedro');
pedro.on('name',()=>{
    console.log('my name is ' + pedro.name);
});

pedro.emit('name')
```

FYI, you don't need to instantiate the class EventEmitter to extend from it. You can delete second line if you are not using object `eventEmitter`.